# Objective-C on Windows 7 using GCC

Tags: objective-c, gcc, windows-7, batch-file

I am learning `Objective-C`. I setup GNU Step(GCC) on Windows 7 to compile and run `Objective-C`. I run `cmd.exe` and type

`1: gcc -x objective-c <filename.m> -o <obj.o>`

then I type

`2: obj.o`

and the `Objective-C` file executes. First please tell me whether I'm on the track or not. If yes then how can I make a `BAT` file to do these two steps? Else tell me the right way to compile and run an `Objective-C` file on GCC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically, you use `.o` as the file extension for intermediate files, not for the executable. It can be confusing to have `.o` files that are actually `.exe` files

Comment: @Petesh In unix sys `.o` is the extension for executable produced by compiler.

Comment: @whoone Yes you are doing right thing. First step compiles your file and convert it into `.o` file. Which in next step you run.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore it's the extension of the intermediate binary, prior to it being linked as an executable. `.o` files are the result of `gcc -c`, the final executable is as a result of `gcc` perfoming the linking step (or it being manually linked using ld)

Comment: @Rathore - If I compile using `gcc -o filename filename.m` and then run it using `filename` then will be also correct form?

Comment: @Petesh I'm no sure but that's what I have read..

Comment: @whoone Try it and see the result..

Comment: @Rathore - Yes same. But I don't know whether it's using Objective-C compiling process or normal C. My code is a simple `printf()` like a C code, that's why I'm confused on c and objective-c.

Comment: Because I don't know `make`, please tell me `how`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write a simple GNUmakefile and build your sources with GNUstep-make (should already be installed) here's how to write one. Put it in the same folder with the source file and type make.

http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/node2.html

Answer (score 0):

GNU Step shell is just like unix shell so your `.bat` file won't execute.
So create a `.sh` file

e.g.

runFile.sh

```
echo "Argument $1"
gcc -x objective-c $1 -o MyObj.o
MyObj.o
```

Where `$1` is the argument passed to the `.sh` file `user/myDir>sh runFile.sh MyFile.m`

---

**Edited**

This is the `cm.sh` that I have used when I run GNU step

cmd.sh

```
gcc -o hello hello.m -I /c/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L  /c/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

And this is the `hello.m` program that I have run

```
#import  <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main()
{
printf("helkjfkaskdhfkjas\n\n");

NSObject *obj;
NSString *str1 = @"Hello";
NSString *str = [[NSSstring alloc] initWithString:str1];

printf("cnst = %d     var =%d",[str1 retainCount],[str retainCount]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then where is filename? `set "param1=filename.m"` something like this?

Comment: `'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Not working on `windows`